# Meaning of "ratbane"

Tags: meaning

> But the faithful were not troubled by consistency,'the bugbear of little minds'- and the
>        **ratbane** of inconsistent bigots.

What does *ratbane* mean? There is [a clue on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratbane), but I don't understand it. I should mention the sentence is from Eric Temple Bell's *Men of Mathematics*.

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ratsbane

Comment: So, you are saying you know *bugbear* but not *ratbane*?

Comment: @GEdgar I've found "bugbear"'s meaning in dictionary but "ratbane" can't be found

Comment: @Jasper, what is the reason for editing? What was wrong with the former structure ? I've heard it in a Period drama

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rat poison. It says that consistency would be fatal to bigots.

Comment: Doesn't either.  It says consistency would be fatal to inconsistent bigots, not bigots in general.

Comment: Thanks. Can you take a look at this post also? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124780/trade-off-between-conciseness-and-detail-in-learning-vocabulary